# Angular / Firestore - Create a number of documents based on a specific value

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have an input where a user can define a 'game count' and a 'player name'.

If the user enters '10' for the game count, is it possible that when adding a new user, that a sub-collection is created called 'game_scores' where 10 documents are added for each of the 10 scores?

In firestore, the structure would end up being:

Players (player name added here) > Game_Scores > 10 documents (each having a value of 'game_score:0')

Or alternatively, would it be easier / more efficient to create an Array node on the player collection for the 10 scores?

The following function adds a user fine to the user collection. I'm just unsure of how to create a sub-collection with a set number of documents.

```
addUser(userName){
  const newUser: any = {
    userName: userName,
  };

  this.usersCollection.add(newUser).then((docRef) => {
    const gameID = docRef.id;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do that. Lets say you have this object:

```
const games = [
 {
  game_score: 0,
  ..
  ..
 },
 {
  game_score: 0,
  ..
  ..
 },
 {
  game_score: 0,
  ..
  ..
 },
]
```

I've added more fields, since you will probably want to do it sometime (timestamp, or any other information about the game.)

so you might iterate this array and:

```
games.forEach(game => {
 this.usersCollection.doc(`${userID}`).collection<any>('games').add(game);
})
```

as simple as that, you can create new nested collections.


**To your question if its better to do it in a new collection or in object:**

I think its better to do it in a new collection, since you may want in the future to add authentication and security rules and to prevent access from other players to unique fields from each user, so in this way, you can restrict the games to a public data and prevent other users from the private data of the user.

**EDIT:**
If you dont have an object an as you said in the comments you just have a value of games you may do something like:
**In your code:**

```
setGameCount = (gameCount) => {
 const gCount = +gameCount; // <-- since you pass the value from the input, we convert it to number from string.
 const userID = 'yourUserID'; // <-- which user you are initialize
 for(let i=0 ; i< gCount; i++){
    const game = {
     game_score: 0,
    }
    this.usersCollection.doc(`${userID}`).collection<any>('games').add(game);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dax! - Quick question, if I have the following HTML, how is it possible to hook up the inputs numerical value to the amount of items in the 'Games' object?

<input #gameCount placeholder="Set Game Count" />
<button (click)="setGameCount()"> Set Game Count </button>

Comment: you should pass inside the setGameCount(gameCount.value)

Comment: Thanks. Yup, I've naturally passed that through, but I'm unsure of how to build an object with that number.

Comment: @ETX, well anyway its not related to this topic, if you my answer helped you please mark as answered and if you have any other problems or you need help in any thing else, open new topic with these questions, since its not related to the current problem. Cheers and good luck !

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time. I'll mark this as correct, however I'm unable to test if it works because I'm unsure of how to progress past the first section in your proposed answer.

Comment: K, i will update the answer with simpler direction, one sec

Comment: @ETX check now, I've just created generic for loop, and just add new game to the new collection, you may upgrade it as you need but this is the basic

Comment: Perfect, absolute legend! Thanks for your time.